# .svg included incorrectly in two-column IEEE conference template

Tags: floats, ieeetran, svg

Unlike other figures, my `.svg` figure is never in the middle of the column and its right part is out of the page. Here is my **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{natbib} % for the bibliography
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{algorithm} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{array} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdwtools/
\usepackage{eqparbox} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eqparbox/
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/
\usepackage{stfloats} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sttools/
\usepackage{url} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/misc/
% for TikZ drawing
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, positioning, fit}
\usepackage{color}
% for .svg inclusion
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{relsize}


\begin{document}

% INCORRECT: left aligned with a column and right side out of page
\section{section Heading Here}
Section goes here.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{0.2\columnwidth}  
    \includesvg{239}
    \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}

% CORRECT: right in the middle of one column
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{fig}
    \caption{Simulation Results}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}\\

\end{document}
```

How may I fix it?

Comment: Is `svgwidth` sonething you set for that package? That interface would be extremely unconventional. Why don't you convert the svg to PDF and include it that way?

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks! I read a tutorial that indicates me to do so. Regrading the way you mention to include svg, could you please kindly make an answer on how to do that? As long as the svg is in properly, I actually don't care how I do it. :D

Answer (score 1):

Slightly too long to be a comment, but here's my advice:

I cannot get your example to compile at all on my system (even with replacement images),
  but I suspect if you had `[width=.2\columnwidth]`
  as an optional argument to `\includesvg`
  (such that it looks like your later call to `\includegraphics`),
  it would work fine.
`\def\svgwidth{…}`, while relevant to the package,
  may not actually be used as you use it.
Use the interface defined in the documentation:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering 
    \includesvg[width=\columnwidth]{239}
    \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}
```

As for positioning your figure in the middle of the column, just add `[!h]` to your first `figure` environment, but see also [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017) as to why this is a bad idea typographically.

If you *really* want that, modify your code like so:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering 
    \includesvg[width=\columnwidth]{239}
    \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}
```